# Pandas Convert 'NA' to NaN during converting dataframe to .csv/.xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-science

My main Excel Sheet:- [Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G34to.png)
My code:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
p = Path(r'/.')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) 
                for f in p.rglob('test.xlsx')],
               ignore_index=True)
df
df.to_excel("final.xlsx")
```

The output is:- [My 'NA' strings get convert to NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHhO6.png)

[and after converting the dataframe to excel all my NA sting to blank.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p630.png)

The solution to this was :- **keep_default_na=False**
while reading the datasheet.

Comment: its the behaviour. what do you want to change ?

Comment: @srinath my concern is the 'NA' is a string in my orginal excel sheet and when i merge multiple sheets together as one it converts the 'NA ' string to NaN

Comment: in your case, does string 'NA' denotes anything else?

Comment: Yes "NA" does have a meaning in my sheet but pandas convert NA to NaN but I found a working solution. **keep_default_na=False** while reading the files.

Comment: was about to say that. glad you found out.